# Odoo SendAsDenied; <catchall email> not allowed to send as <external email>

Tags: odoo, office365

I've got Odoo 17 setup on my AWS server in a Docker container, and I'm trying to use our Microsoft 365 as an SMTP "relay server" per the excellent instructions in this article:
https://ventor.tech/guides/how-to-configure-emails-to-work-with-office-365-and-odoo/

Here's a diagram of how it's supposed to work:

[image: email relay server diagram]

In Office 365 Exchange admin, I've setup my "catchall" email address as "erp@my_company.com" and it's acting as a "relay server" for all emails not matching an existing internal company email address.

I've setup an Odoo CRM "sales team" whose email in Odoo is "sales.us@my_company.com". Then I send an email from my personal Gmail account "personal@gmail.com" to that Odoo email address. It's supposed to setup a "lead" in the CRM and then forward the email from "personal@gmail.com" to whoever is setup as a "follower" on that Odoo CRM sales team. However, the following error occurs:

```
odoo_odoo    | 2023-12-08 17:36:59,743 1 INFO odoo odoo.addons.mail.models.fetchmail: start checking for new emails on outlook server Incoming Email Catchall Server
odoo_odoo    | 2023-12-08 17:36:59,824 1 INFO odoo odoo.addons.microsoft_outlook.models.microsoft_outlook_mixin: Microsoft Outlook: reuse existing access token. It expires in 16 minutes
odoo_odoo    | 2023-12-08 17:37:01,497 1 INFO odoo odoo.addons.mail.models.mail_thread: Routing mail from "Sean McCarthy" <personal@gmail.com> to sales.us@my_company.com with Message-Id <CA+F-SghHyPtADO1O3-Khq871yLdV4rA@mail.gmail.com>: direct alias match: ('crm.lead', 0, {'type': 'opportunity', 'team_id': 5}, 2, mail.alias(7,))
odoo_odoo    | 2023-12-08 17:37:02,152 1 INFO odoo odoo.addons.mail.tools.mail_validation: The (optional) `flanker` Python module is not installed,so email validation will fallback to email_normalize.
odoo_odoo    | 2023-12-08 17:37:02,286 1 INFO odoo odoo.addons.microsoft_outlook.models.microsoft_outlook_mixin: Microsoft Outlook: reuse existing access token. It expires in 53 minutes
odoo_odoo    | 2023-12-08 17:37:04,423 1 INFO odoo odoo.addons.base.models.ir_mail_server: Mail delivery failed via SMTP server 'None'.
odoo_odoo    | SMTPDataError: 554
odoo_odoo    | 5.2.252 SendAsDenied; erp@my_company.com not allowed to send as personal@gmail.com; STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:SendAsDeniedException.MapiExceptionSendAsDenied; Failed to process message due to a permanent exception with message [BeginDiagnosticData]Cannot submit message. ... [EndDiagnosticData] [Hostname=YT2P288MB0353.CANP288.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]
odoo_odoo    | 2023-12-08 17:37:04,423 1 ERROR odoo odoo.addons.mail.models.mail_mail: failed sending mail (id: 119) due to Mail Delivery Failed
odoo_odoo    | Mail delivery failed via SMTP server 'None'.
```

In Odoo, here are my “System Parameters” in settings:
[image]

How to fix that `SendAsDenied; erp@my_company.com not allowed to send as personal@gmail.com` exception so Odoo can properly relay the message? The message is arriving in Odoo and the CRM "lead" is created, but it's not forwarding the original email to the "followers" of the CRM sales team.

Comment: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/17.0/applications/general/email_communication/email_servers.html#use-a-default-from-email-address

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this solved the problem, but I went into **Settings / Technical / Email / Alias Domains** and changed the **"Default From Alias"** from "notifications" to "erp" (same as my "Catchall Alias"), and it started forwarding customer lead emails from "erp@my_company.com" (my default from email) to the "followers" of the sales team, as wanted/required.

[image: picture of where to find Odoo "Alias Domain" settings]

[image: picture of Odoo "Alias Domain" settings]